# How to update docker web app without killing connections?

Tags: git, docker, go, nginx, continuous-deployment

I have a `docker-compose.yml` which has two services: a database and my Go app. My CI/CD pipeline calls the server that is hosting this docker container and runs this bash script:

```
git fetch &> /dev/null
diffs=$(git diff master origin/master)

if [ ! -z "$diffs" ]
then
    echo "Pulling code from GitHub..."
    git checkout master
    git pull origin master

    # update server
    docker-compose up --build -d

    # kill all unused docker containers
    docker system prune -f
else
    echo "Already up to date"
fi
```

The problem with this is that if there are any outstanding http connections to my container they will be terminated. I have used `"gopkg.in/tylerb/graceful.v1"` to wait for outstanding connections to finish before terminating but this could technically never stop if clients kept making separate overlapping requests.

This service is behind an nginx reverse proxy:

```
upstream goapp {
    server 127.0.0.1:8080;
}
```

An idea I had would be to deploy the docker app on a new port (not sure if possible using docker-compose) and then tell nginx to add a new server to the `upstream` (e.g `server 127.0.0.1:8081;) for all new incoming connections. Then allow the container on`8080`to gracefully close (then somehow delete from the`upstream`). Is this possible or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: "but this could technically never stop" -- not true. Once the shutdown begins, no more connections are accepted. So your upper-bound is whatever your HTTP connection timeout is.

Comment: How do you know that `Once the shutdown begins, no more connections are accepted.`?

Comment: The normal behavior is to start the new service, which begins accepting connections immediately, then start the graceful shutdown on the old service, which will finalize any pending requests, then die. I don't know how docker-compose handles that. Kubernetes does that by default.

Comment: Because that's the definition of "Graceful shutdown" Any other behavior would, by definition, be a bug.

Comment: And incidentally, graceful shutdown is now supported in the standard library since Go 1.8. No need for third-party tools any more. See [here](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Server.Shutdown). The documentation for which states `Once Shutdown has been called on a server, it may not be reused; future calls to methods such as Serve will return ErrServerClosed`

Comment: Awesome thank you for that. Okay if a user is uploading a large file lets say - this will delay the closing for a long amount of time! So I am looking to start routing the traffic to the new container with the updated code.

Comment: "If a user is uploading a large file this will delay the closing for a long amount of time!" Erm, yes. This is either acceptable to you or it isn't. There is no technical solution here.

Answer (score 0):

Using a single host machine (as indicated by the use of docker-compose) while being concerned about high availability seems VERY odd to me. More on that later.

> **ATTENTION** The following is simplified, vastly in parts. Furthermore, the terminology is off here and there for the sake of simplicity.

However, there is a notion of a service, which is available both [for docker swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/how-swarm-mode-works/services/) and [for Kubernetes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/). A service is a virtual loadbalancer/transparent reverse proxy with awareness of its backends which can be backed by a basically arbitrary number of containers or pods, in Kubernetes parlay (henceforth shortened to containers, since this is not technically false for Kubernetes, either). Those containers of course each run your application. The engine is aware of wether a container is shutting down or becomes unavailable and routes requests to containers which are alive. So far, so good.

Now, both engines have a different notion, which is called „rolling updates“. What actually happens there is that *if* you have your service backed by more than one container is something like this:

> Hi, I am your orchestration engine!
>   Uh, you want to update the image for the containers backing service X?
>   Lets see... Well, X has two backing containers, so we can do a rolling
>   update. Uh, a new request for the service: Sending it to the second
>   container. While it is processed, I fire up a container with the new
>   image... Takes a while... There it is! Sending all new requests to the
>   updated container. Now shutting down the first of the old containers... Down! Firing up a second container with the new image...
>   Done! Great, now sending all new requests to the updated containers.
>   Trying to stop the remaining old container... Waiting till it processed
>   the request, but at most 30s, then I‘ll kill it... Ah, not required,
>   already shut down...
>
> I am pleased to inform you that I successfully updated service X to use new containers with the shiny new version of your application!

#### Little secret

docker-compose should *technically* be able to do the same, if you scale up your service to > 1 and then change the compose file and then do a

```
docker-compose up
```

However, all this fuzz about not loosing a connection and then running on a single machine seems like trying to install a battleship cannon on a rowing boat. My advice: if your service actually uses ephemeral containers (if you use a mount in any way, shape or form you most likely do not), use docker swarm. Otherwise, use Kubernetes. While it‘s learning curve might be a bit steep (in the beginning, it flattens out pretty quickly), it is worth it in more complicated setups.

**Edit** Keeping individual *sessions* including current uploads is a totally different thing and while not entirely impossible, requires rather sophisticated reverse proxies and/or equally sophisticated application setup. Usually, it is easier to announce a maintenance window.